# SQL Server view cast datetime to monthname

Tags: sql-server, datetime, view, casting

How can I cast in the view the column from type datetime, `dbo.Verkaufstransaktion.VerkaufDatum`, to monthname

```
SELECT         
    dbo.Artikel.ArtikelName, dbo.Artikel.Preis, 
    dbo.Kategorie.KategorieName, dbo.Mitarbeiter.MitarbeiterName, 
    dbo.Verkaufstransaktion.Monat, dbo.Verkaufstransaktion.VerkaufAnzahl, 
    dbo.Artikel.ArtikelKey, dbo.Mitarbeiter.MitarbeiterKey, 
    dbo.Kategorie.KategorieKey, dbo.Verkaufstransaktion.VerkaufDatum
FROM
    dbo.Artikel 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Kategorie ON dbo.Artikel.Id_Kategorie = dbo.Kategorie.Id 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Lagerzuweisung ON dbo.Artikel.Id = dbo.Lagerzuweisung.Id_Artikel 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Mitarbeiter ON dbo.Artikel.Id = dbo.Mitarbeiter.Id 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Verkaufstransaktion ON dbo.Artikel.Id = dbo.Verkaufstransaktion.Id_ Artikel 
                            AND dbo.Mitarbeiter.Id = dbo.Verkaufstransaktion.Id_Mitarbeiter
```

Comment: You should tag your question with your actual database, which is presumably some version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't "cast".  Just extract the appropriate date part:

```
SELECT . . .
       datename(month, dbo.Verkaufstransaktion.VerkaufDatum) as MonthName
```

Your query would be easier to write and to read with table aliases:

```
SELECT a.ArtikelName, a.Preis, k.KategorieName, m.MitarbeiterName,
       v.Monat, v.VerkaufAnzahl, a.ArtikelKey, m.MitarbeiterKey, 
       k.KategorieKey,
       datename(month, v.VerkaufDatum) as MonthName
FROM dbo.Artikel a INNER JOIN
     dbo.Kategorie k
     ON a.Id_Kategorie =k .Id INNER JOIN
     dbo.Lagerzuweisung l
     ON a.Id = l.Id_Artikel INNER JOIN
     dbo.Mitarbeiter m
     ON a.Id = m.Id INNER JOIN
     dbo.Verkaufstransaktion v
     ON a.Id = v.Id_Artikel AND m.Id = v.Id_Mitarbeiter
```

Comment: In the SQL Pane in my view, before the SELECT i will change the language and i add the command "SET LANGUAGE german". I become this error message "SQL text cannot be represented in the grid pane and diagram pane.". Also when i execute only the command "SET LANGUAGE german" .